# VSCode/MinGW-w64: How to stop the GDB debugger at a breakpoint inside a DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64, vscode-debugger, win64

We are developing a Win64 DLL using the GCC toolchain (MinGW-w64) in version 9.2.0. As IDE we use VisualStudio Code (version 1.47.3) with the C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing plugin from Microsoft (version 0.30.0).

Unfortunately, we cannot set any breakpoints inside our DLL.

The situation is the same if we attach the DLL within our TestApplication statical or dynamical by using LoadLibrary.

Starting the GDB as a console process allows us to set a breakpoint in the DLL and stop at that line, but we miss the convenience of the IDE. I assume there is an issue in the configuration of the VSCode project or within the C/C++ plugin.

We use the following launch.json file:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

    {
        "name": "gcc.exe build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Win64/TestApplication.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "${workspaceFolder}/minGW-w64/bin/gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": false
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "build-all",
        "avoidWindowsConsoleRedirection": true,
        "logging": {
            "trace": false,
            "traceResponse": false,
            "engineLogging": true
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

**Update: 17-Aug-2020:
The reason is the missing symbols from the DLL, which cannot be loaded.
Even if I try to load the symbol file for the DLL while the debugger is starting, it always removes these symbols when loading the host application. The only workaround that I have found is to manually reload the symbol file within a first breakpoint that I can only enter by its address.**

Is anybody able to debug a Win64 DLL with the same toolchain?

Comment: @S.S.Anne: I agree, but with a command-line based debugger I lose the overview of the code.
Nowadays I don't really want to go blind and spend hours rummaging through log files.

Comment: Even if I load the DLL's symbol file by starting the debugger, it will be removed again when the host application will be started.
To do this, I added the `miDebuggerArgs` line in launch.json: `-x $ {workspaceFolder} /GDBLoadSym.cmd"`, where GDBLoadSym.cmd contains the following line: `symbol-file My.dll`. I am currently working with the following workaround: I determined the address of the first called function and set this address as a breakpoint in GDBLoadSym.cmd. When this breakpoint is reached, I can manually reload the symbols in the VSCode Debug Console with `-exec symbol-file My.dll`.